# How to increase the timer before drive spins-down?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-disk, power-management

I use Ubuntu 12 beta on a Lenovo Z575. I noticed that the disk spins down a few seconds after the last operation. When I am working, e.g. in the vim and write quite often, it spins-up and -down frequently. This causes vim to freeze for a second.

I used `hdparm` but it didn't change anything:

```
hdparm -S 24 /dev/sda # 2 minutes standby time
```

and I see (and hear) that the disk is idle or working:

```
hdparm -C /dev/sda
drive state is: standby
# or...
drive state is: active/idle
```

I have `laptop-mode-tools` already installed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your computer works in laptop mode. To change the behaviour of laptop mode in Ubuntu you should change parameters in file /etc/laptop-mode/laptop-mode.conf . These parameters among others could affect you:

```
#
# Idle timeout values. (hdparm -S)
# Default is 2 hours on AC (NOLM_HD_IDLE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS=7200) and 20 seconds
# for battery and for AC with laptop mode on.
LM_AC_HD_IDLE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS=20 
LM_BATT_HD_IDLE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS=20 
NOLM_HD_IDLE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS=7200

#
# Power management for HD (hdparm -B values)
# 
BATT_HD_POWERMGMT=1 
LM_AC_HD_POWERMGMT=254 
NOLM_AC_HD_POWERMGMT=254
```

---

Also in Debian distributions there could be some parameters in the file /etc/default/laptop-mode (but my Ubuntu 12.04 does not have this file).

There are some parameters that controls idle timeout that (here a citation):

**AC_HD/BATT_HD**
`The idle timeout that should be set on your hard drive when laptop mode
is active (BATT_HD) and when it is not active (AC_HD). The defaults are
20 seconds (value 4) for BATT_HD  and 2 hours (value 244) for AC_HD. The
possible values are those listed in the manual page for "hdparm" for the
"-S" option.`

---

There is additionally a kernel laptop mode. Computer that works in kernel laptop mode will be spinning disk up slower but it should not change the spinning down behaviour.

To check kernel laptop mode try:
`cat /proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode` 
If the value is 1 or more it means the computer works in laptop mode. To disable laptop mode set it to 0.

A cite from https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/laptops/laptop-mode.txt :
`"The
result of this is that after a disk has spun down, it will not be spun up
anymore to write dirty blocks, because those blocks had already been written
immediately after the most recent read operation."`

Additional information about the kernel laptop mode could be found at site given above.

Comment: well, it *is* a laptop... Lenovo Z575

Comment: @JakubM. One of "feature" of [laptop mode](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7539) is to save battery by often suspending the disk. ;-) See [laptop mode tools](http://samwel.tk/laptop_mode/) . You can try to tweak your setting in `laptop-mode.conf` (probably in /etc - I don't know Ubuntu very well)

Comment: laptop_mode doesn't actually spin the disk down, it just flushes all writes whenever there's any disk activity to get them out of the way so the disk *can* spin down and not be woken back up soon by pending writes.

Comment: @psusi I did not write anything contrary to your comment, and actually my answer is a little simplification of the problem so I don't know why you down voted the answer

Comment: @digital_infinity, I down voted because setting laptop_mode to zero will *not* keep the disk from spinning down.

Comment: @psusi - certainly it will not directly change, but indirectly it changes the disk spinning behaviour. Also note, that I had written the answer as the first and probably the question was not fully specified. For me downvoting the answer by you *was unfair* because the answer is with regard to the topic and it is not incorrect.

Comment: The answer is incorrect since setting it to zero will not change how soon the drive spins down after the last access, and that is what the question is about.  Also the value is not 1 for true, but the number of seconds after the last access that all dirty pages should be flushed, and is usually set to 2.

Comment: @psusi notice that part of the question: " it **spins-up** and -dow frequently, what is rather annoying (and causes the vim to freeze for a second...)" . So despite the topic the OPS is asking about the spinning-up too. Thanks for all suggestions I added additional information to the answer so please give me back the points  :-)

Comment: The spin up is clearly expected after the disk has spin down.  The question is specifically asking why it spins down sooner than he requested with `hdparm`. Laptop-mode-tools just runs `hdparm` for you, so the only reason to mention laptop-mode-tools is to remind the OP to make sure they did not install it and configure it for the shorter interval, and it is changing the setting after he uses `hdparm`.  Also the kernel laptop mode setting does not make the disk spin up slower; it lets it spin down by flushing all of the dirty pages at once and stop rather than trickling every few seconds.

Comment: @psusi *it lets it spin down by flushing all of the dirty pages at once and stop rather than trickling every few seconds* - what is clearly written in the cited sites. If you read my answer more carefully it is written in the answer too. (hint: at the end)

Answer (score 1):

Try `hdparm -B 254 /dev/sda`

My drive seems to ignore -S commands but listens to -B commands.

Comment: Yea, most laptop drives seem to use the old depreciated APM commands that -B uses.